# Can't find my mistake- abstract error

Tags: c++, design-patterns, abstract-class

4 hours of misery- tried everything... HELP!

trying to use design patters for the first time, and dont know what Im doing wrong...

Below are some pieces of the code. the errors I get are:

```
Error   1   error C2259: 'MyBscImplementation' : cannot instantiate abstract class  
Error   3   error C2259: 'MyBscImplementation' : cannot instantiate abstract class
Error   5   error C2259: 'MyBscImplementation' : cannot instantiate abstract class
Error   2   error C2248: 'MyPhdImplementation::MyPhdImplementation' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MyPhdImplementation'  
Error   4   error C2248: 'MyPhdImplementation::MyPhdImplementation' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MyPhdImplementation'  
Error   6   error C2248: 'MyPhdImplementation::MyPhdImplementation' : cannot access private member declared in class 'MyPhdImplementation'
```

myStudFactory.h:

```
#ifndef __MYSTUDFACTORY_H
#define __MYSTUDFACTORY_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#include "myStudImpl.h"
#include "myBscImpl.h"
#include "myMscImpl.h"
#include "myPhdImpl.h"

class MyStudentFactory
{
public:
    static MyStudentImplementation* CreateStudent(const string& studentType, string name, int id, MySubj* s)
    {
        MyStudentImplementation* ptrStudent = 0;
        if(studentType == "B.Sc")
            ptrStudent = new MyBscImplementation(s, name, id);
        if(studentType == "M.Sc")
            ptrStudent = new MyMscImplementation(s, name, id);
        if(studentType == "Ph.D")
            ptrStudent = new MyPhdImplementation(s, name, id);
        return ptrStudent; ///////////////////////!!!!!
        //*%^$&^$@#%//
    }
private:
    MyStudentFactory();
    ~MyStudentFactory();
};


#endif
```

myStudImpl.h:

```
#ifndef __MYSTUDIMPL_H
#define __MYSTUDIMPL_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

class MyStudentImplementation
{
public:
    MyStudentImplementation(string name="NULL", int id=0);
    virtual void tell() const = 0;
    string getName() const {return studentName;}
    int getId() const {return studentId;}

protected:
    string studentName;
    int studentId;
};


#endif
```

myExamObs.h:

```
#ifndef __MYEXAMOBS_H
#define __MYEXAMOBS_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
#include "myDate.h"

class MySubj;

class MyExamObs
{
public:
    virtual ~MyExamObs() {}
    virtual void Update(MySubj* ChangeSubject, const myDate& exam_date) const = 0;
protected:
    MyExamObs() {}
    MySubj* sbj;
};

#endif
```

myExamObs.cpp:

```
#include "myExamObs.h"
#include "myBscImpl.h"
#include "mySubj.h"

MyBscImplementation::MyBscImplementation(MySubj* s, string name, int id) : MyStudentImplementation(name, id)
{
    sbj = s;
    sbj->Attach(this);
}

MyBscImplementation::~MyBscImplementation()
{
    sbj->Detach(this);
}

void MyBscImplementation::Update(MySubj* ChangeSubject, const myDate& exam_date)
{
    if (ChangeSubject == sbj)
    {
        cout << studentName + " had been informed that the exam was postponed to: "; 
        exam_date.print();
    }
}
```

myBscImpl.h:

```
#ifndef __MYBSCIMPL_H
#define __MYBSCIMPL_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

#include "myExamObs.h"
#include "myStudImpl.h"
#include "myDate.h"

class MyBscImplementation : public MyStudentImplementation, public MyExamObs
{
public:
    MyBscImplementation(string name, int id);
    void tell();
    MyBscImplementation(MySubj* s, string name, int id);
    ~MyBscImplementation();
    void Update(MySubj* ChangeSubject, const myDate& exam_date);
};

#endif
```

myBscImpl.cpp:

```
#include "myBscImpl.h"

MyBscImplementation::MyBscImplementation( string name, int id ) : MyStudentImplementation(name, id)
{

}

void MyBscImplementation::tell() 
{
    cout << "BScstudent name is:" << studentName <<", Id is: " << studentId << endl; 
}
```

Comment: Is that the exact error? Seems like there should be a line number somewhere in there.

Comment: HINT: `void Update(...)` is not the same as `void Update(...) const`...

Answer (score 1):

In `CreateStudent()` you can't instantiate a `MyBscImplementation` object because `MyBscImplementation` inherits from `MyStudentImplementation` but does not implement the pure virtual function `void tell() const` - it does implement `void tell()` but that's not the same function signature.

You haven't given the code for `MyPhdImplementation` so I can't tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: I think you should mention that it does not implement `tell()` because the `const` is missing, since `MyBscImplementation` has a `tell()` member function. The same applies to `MyExamObs::Update(...)`.

Comment: @FlorianSowade: Yes, correct. In fact the first time I read this through I was *sure* there was no `MyBscImplementation::tell()` - my eyes are playing tricks!